# Let $D \subset \Bbb R$ and $f : D \to \Bbb R, f(x)=e^x$. Show that $f$ is Lipschitz on an interval $[-k, k] \subset D$, where $k \in \Bbb N$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $D \subset \Bbb R$ and $f : D \to \Bbb R, f(x)=e^x$. Show that $f$ is Lipschitz on an interval $[-k, k] \subset D$, where $k \in \Bbb N$.

Doesn't this follow from mean value theorem? Since $f$ is continuous on $[-k, k]$ and differentiable on $(-k,k)$ we have $$|e^k-e^{-k}| = e^c|k-(-k)| =2k \cdot e^c$$ for some $c \in (-k, k)$. So the Lipschitz constant would be $e^c$?

Answer (score 0):

The result folows from MVT but your proof is wrong. The correct proof is as follows:
Let $x,y \in [-k,k]$. Then $|e^{x}-e^{y} |=|x-y|e^{c}$ for some $c$ between $x$ and $y$ (hence also between $-k$ and $+k$) so $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq e^{k} |x-y|$. [Note that your Lipschitz constant should not depend on the points $x,y$].